# How do you close form1, open form2 and soon after returning to form1 and closing form2? I'm having trouble with reference

Tags: vb.net, forms, winforms

--

```
Private Sub ACTIVECLOSEToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ACTIVECLOSEToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim Nform As New Aba_Principal_SecondShift
    Nform.Show()
    Hide()
End Sub

Private Sub CREATEWORKNUMBERToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CREATEWORKNUMBERToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim Nform2 As New Aba_Principal_ThirdShift
    Nform2.Show()
    Hide()
End Sub
```

My question is because if I put the reverse process I get the following error: "A reference could not be added. Adding this project as a reference would cause circular dependency."

Comment: You're hiding, not closing those Forms. You could use the default instances that VB.Net provides to reference your Forms. No need to `New` a Form here, just `Show()` it. It would be bad in C#, because you'ld `new` an instance of a Form that already exists (it's just hidden). The second Form could be closed instead of hidden, it depends on what it's used for.

Comment: What do you mean by *reverse process*?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe This will help:
 I just modified your code, i have declared a fc as a form and assign a value to it as an
open form in your application, after that i have created a `if statement` then if if `fc` is an openform then close it and show the form you want to show.
PS: Dont forget to add `Try Catch Exception` in your code to prevent the application from crashing.

```
Private Sub ACTIVECLOSEToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ACTIVECLOSEToolStripMenuItem.Click
       Dim fc As Form = Application.OpenForms("Form2")
        If fc IsNot Nothing Then fc.Close()
        form1.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub CREATEWORKNUMBERToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CREATEWORKNUMBERToolStripMenuItem.Click
       Dim fc As Form = Application.OpenForms("Form1")
        If fc IsNot Nothing Then fc.Close()
        form2.Show()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As Jimi said in the comments, you do not need to dim the new forms; you just need to open them using `.show()`, as shown below. This is assuming that you have called your first form `Nform1` and you second form `Nform2`. If not, just replace the names to the ones you have chosen

```
Private Sub ACTIVECLOSEToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ACTIVECLOSEToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Nform1.Show()
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub CREATEWORKNUMBERToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CREATEWORKNUMBERToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Nform2.Show()
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

You might have a problem when closing the startup form, since by default, visual basic will close your entire programme when this happens, as you can see below under `Shutdown mode:`

[image]

You can change this to `When last form closes` instead:

[image]

You can find these in the settings application tab of your project. Below is an example of where to find it:

[image]